# gRPC C++, client: "14: Connect Failed"

Tags: c++, grpc

We are running "helloworld" example from https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/cpp.html#update-a-grpc-service and we received the following ERROR:

> 14: Connect Failed
>
> Greeter received: RPC failed.

The server and the client are listening on: `0.0.0.0:50051`. The Server is running.
First we receive just a packet on the server and the client crashes, I checked it with tcpdump. We checked on different hosts as well as on the same host but it didn't work for either cases.
Should we change a different IP or different Port number?

Comment: Solved it! you need to unset your proxy at both sides with the following command:

$unset http_proxy
$http_proxy=""

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue on my PC(OS: ubuntu 16.04 LTS, protobuf 3.4.0)

so I search for the reason and I found this:

### Reason

> If on a linux machine, the environment has the usual "http_proxy" environment variable configured, gRPC will take that into account when trying to connect, however, will then proceed to ignore the companion no_proxy setting:
>
> For example:

```
$ env
http_proxy=http://106.1.216.121:8080
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1

$ ./greeter_client
D0306 16:00:11.419586349 1897 combiner.c:351] C:0x25a9290 finish old_state=3
D0306 16:00:11.420527744 1896 tcp_client_posix.c:179] CLIENT_CONNECT: ipv4:106.1.216.121:8080: on_writable: error="No Error"
D0306 16:00:11.420567382 1896 combiner.c:145] C:0x25a69a0 create
D0306 16:00:11.420581887 1896 tcp_client_posix.c:119] CLIENT_CONNECT: ipv4:106.1.216.121:8080: on_alarm: error="Cancelled"
I0306 16:00:11.420617663 1896 http_connect_handshaker.c:319] Connecting to server 127.0.0.1:50051 via HTTP proxy ipv4:106.1.216.121:8080
```

> Basically, it's using the http_proxy url to connect even though localhost is in the no_proxy list. Since the default for no_proxy includes localhost on most linux machines; the end result is that any user with an http_proxy configured will never be able to connect to localhost. --- [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoVFE.png)]

---

### Other [solution](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6862#issuecomment-234248967)

> You can enable grpc tracing with
>   `export GRPC_TRACE=all && ./greeter_server` and same thing for the client.

### **Verification**

Terminal 1
[image]
Terminal 2
[image]

That should do the trick

ps. for more information about GRPC_TRACE - [gRPC environment variables](https://grpc.io/grpc/core/md_doc_environment_variables.html)

#### Reference

1. [gRPC doesn't respect the no_proxy environment variable](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9989)

Comment: This issue has been fixed in latest grpc version, but thanks for your valuable comments anyway, saved my day.

Comment: @Fei Sure thing!